# Sobolev spaces - embedding - exercise

Tags: partial-differential-equations, sobolev-spaces

I have to show that $H^{2}(\Omega) \subset \subset H^1(\Omega)$. I think the Arzela - Ascoli theorem can help.. .I dont know how to start this exercise . I am beginner in Sobolev spaces.. someone can give me a hint ?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Rellich-Kondrachov theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rellich%E2%80%93Kondrachov_theorem) implies that for bounded Lipschitz domains $\Omega$ the embedding $H^1(\Omega)\subset L^2(\Omega)$ is compact. To use this fact, observe that the $H^2$ norm of a function is comparable to the sum of $H^1$ norms of its partial derivatives.  Thus, if $(u_k)$ is a bounded sequence in $H^2$, then the partial derivatives $\partial u_k/\partial x_1$ form a bounded sequence in $H^1$. By Rellich-Kondrachov the sequence of derivatives has a strongly convergent subsequence in $L^2$. Same works for derivatives with respect to other variables. Thus, $\nabla u_k$ converge strongly in $L^2$. You can get the convergence of $u_k$ themselves in $L^2$ from the [Poincaré inequality](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poincar%C3%A9_inequality) after choosing a further  subsequence for which the averages $u_\Omega$ converge. (The latter is possible because the averages are bounded.)

For the future: the geometric properties  of $\Omega$ and of its boundary are  important when Sobolev spaces are involved. They should be stated in the question.

Comment: i forget to say that $\partial \Omega$ is $C^1$.sorry. your solution works in my case  =). your solution is beatiful !  thank you !